# Xamarin.Forms problem with install Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Vision

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Today i was working on my ocr scanner app. I tried to install Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Vision from NuGet packages to use the text recognition from photos.

I tried to install latest version 60.1142.1 and 29.0.0.2.

I got this error:

[image: Error]
My installed SDK:

[image: My SDK]

Additionally, i have ImageCropper.Forms, Xam.Plugin.Media in this project, i don't know is this important.

Comment: I forget to write, i tried clean&&build app billion times, it unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: The error says Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Vision is not compatible with .Net Standard. Right now your project is developed in .Net Standard and the plugin is not compatible yet. You may need to wait until they release a .Net standard compatible upgrade of the plugin

Comment: Can not get around this?

Comment: To my knowledge, you may need to wait until the upgrade is released for .Net standard. I am not sure might be you can try getting the plugin project from github and build it to get the output dlls and can refer those dlls in your project

Comment: i'll try, thanks a lot for an idea

Comment: @kifu GooglePlayService.Vision is a "native" implementation and thus is not available via .NetStd, you would need to add it to your Xamarin.Android application project and then you could create a Netstd / Forms' based dependency  and call the native functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you may need to wait until the upgrade is released for .Net standard. I am not sure might be you can try getting the plugin project from github and build it to get the output dlls and can refer those dlls in your project